# Is there a way to retrieve the "Save & Return" link for an incomplete entry?

Tags: cognito-forms

We are using Cognito Forms for an application form to a nonprofit organization. Applications come from people in various parts of the world where computer literacy is not the highest, and we have sent users with incomplete submissions a reminder of the deadline. Some of those users cannot find the original Save & Return link generated when they saved their progress, and I cannot find it in the interface, but I can view and edit their entry while logged in. Is there a way to retrieve these links so we can help those users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

We do not have a way to recover the Save and Resume link. However you can provide them with an edit link to the entry. You can find this on the Entries page under the 'Share' button when an entry is selected. You can learn more about this feature in our [Help Content](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/79/entries/sharing-entries).

Comment: That works perfectly. I'm not sure if there's much difference, this seems to do what we want. I haven't read whether this can be done via API as well, but will check it out.